# Jquery variable using old value on change

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to calculate a value of two variables. Val1 needs to be multiplied with Val2. Val1 an change depending on other user input and is always loaded into '.value'. The first time the calculation is done it is fine. However when Val1 changes on the page it will still use the old value from before, instead of checking the value of Val1 (which is inside '.woocommerce-Price-amount'). It is only using the data that is loaded the first time into Val1.

How can I make sure jquery check the value of Val1 each time 'input.qty' changes?

```
<input type="number" step="1" min="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Aantal" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>93.20</span>
<div class="multTotal"></div>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $( "input.qty" ).change(function() {
        var val1 = $('.woocommerce-Price-amount').val();
        console.log(val1);
       var val1g = val1.replace('<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span>', '');
       var val2 = $('input.qty').val();


       var val1n = parseInt(val1g);
       var val2n = parseInt(val2);

       var total = (val1n * 1) * (val2n * 1);

       $('.multTotal').text(total);
});


});
```

Comment: `return input;` what is `input`? Also the behaviour you describe doesn't make sense. Could you add a snippet to the question demonstrating the problem

Comment: please post html too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. For the simplicity i have added a new class `figures` so that calculation is made simple

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $( "input.qty" ).change(function() {
   debugger
        var val1 =  $('.figures').html();
        var val2 = $('input.qty').val();


       var val1n = parseFloat(val1);
       var val2n = parseFloat(val2);

       var total = (val1n * 1) * (val2n * 1);

       $('.multTotal').text(total);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span><span class='figures'>93.20</span></span>
<div class="multTotal"></div>

<input type='text' class='qty' />
```

Just fill the input value with a number and click outside on the blank area to see the result.

Comment: The problem is, '.value' is a div and not an input field and I unfortunately cannot change that.

Comment: Then you must post the HTML which you are using

Comment: Updated description

Comment: Where is class qty in HTML?

Comment: Check the answer now. And let me know if this is what you want.